# rails stripe - taking a deposit and final payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Looking for best practice and/or improvements on logic.

I’m building an app where a member accepts a bid from a guide on a trip and pays for it. Depending on the situation, the member may pay a deposit at bid acceptance or pay for the whole trip (depends specifically on guide's settings and trip cost). I’m trying to determine the best way to determine what charges have occurred and what charges need to occur in the future.

My thought is to create two tables: charges and payments. Charges will track the successful payments. If the first payment is a deposit then a record will be created in the Payments table with the remaining amount to be paid and due date. This can then be charged in the future.

Is there a better way to handle this? Thanks in advance.